# C# Web Service (404) Not Found.

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

This code used to work and now it stopped working :/

I'm using the same code in other areas of my application and can call the link which works fine.  But in this specific section of my application, it stopped working.

This link is valid and as stated above, it used to work.

Here is the code.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string xmlResult = client.DownloadString(_workContext.AccountingWebServiceLink + "?action=updateprimary&xml=" + strXML);
```

I'm not sure if I need to increase the size of bytes in IIS?   I suspect it might have something to do with the amount of data being sent.

Comment: Can you look at the IIS log on the server offering the service and see what the request is? Do you URLEncode `strXML`?

Comment: I tried UrlEncode and got a 500 error

Comment: @AndrewMorton There's nothing in IIS logs for today's date.

Comment: Maybe the value of `_workContext.AccountingWebServiceLink` is not what you want at that point in the code? If you're getting 404 and 500 errors that suggests that it is connecting to *some* web server.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The _workContext.AccountingWebServiceLink value is correct....I'm getting 400 now even though I UrlEncode.  But when I just make the xml value xml=<Customer></Customer>  it works fine.

Comment: @AndrewMorton When I reduce the amount of XML sent, then it works like a charm.

Comment: I suggest sending the large amount of data in a POST request instead, and adjusting the web service to accept both GET and POST.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141250/discussion-between-orion-and-andrew-morton).